# targetSpeed, targetVelocity Arrival function

Tags: c++, game-physics

I am having trouble figuring out what the equation is to find the speed of a target. I am working with sf::Vector2f to find the arrival function in a 2D game. I just need the equation for target velocity. Can anyone help me out a bit? Here is what I have so far.

```
void Steering::Arrival( sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f target, float maxSpeed, float maxAcceleration, float timeToTarget, float slowRadius, float targetRadius, float targetSpeed, double distance, SteeringOutput& steering ){

timeToTarget = 0.1;

steering.linear = target - position;
distance = sqrt( steering.linear.x * steering.linear.x + steering.linear.y * steering.linear.y);
targetSpeed = maxSpeed * distance / slowRadius;

//Check if arrived at target
if (distance < targetRadius)
{
    MathHelper::ZeroVector;
}

//Check if we are out of the slowRadius
if (distance > slowRadius)
{
    targetSpeed = maxSpeed;
}
else
{
    targetSpeed = maxSpeed * distance / slowRadius;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your problem is not clear.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure how to find the target velocity for the next step in the program.  It is for the Arrive Function for a 2D AI ship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target velocity = (unit vector from Position to Target) * (target speed).
If you need some advance targeting, search for 'Kalman filter'

Comment: Thank you very much rmi.  
Another question, (unit vector from Position to Target), 
does that mean subtracting position from target?

 steering.linear = target - position;
 MathHelper::Normalize( steering.linear );

Like that?

Comment: Thank you so much rmi that seems to have worked I think.  Now would you be able to tell me how to calculate character.velocity?